# Compare products trough URL based on product id - Magento2.4

Tags: magento2, compare

Is it possible to create a compare list with products using a URL with product ID's?

Something like:

```
www.domain.com/catalog/product_compare/index/items/1,2,3,4
```

Or is there another method to easily create a link on productpage to add multiple product id's to compare list?

Comment: Yes, you can do the custom code to added multiple product to compare list.

Comment: @DhirenVasoya Thanks! Can you provide a example?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the code like this.

```
public function __construct(
....
....
\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Compare\ListCompare $listCompare,
....
) {
...
$this->listCompare = $listCompare;
...
}

public function execute()
{
     $productIds = "YOUR_PRODUCT_IDS";
     $this->listCompare->addProducts($productIds);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! But how do we process this into a href element? Because by default is loaded using getPostDataParams.